# How to test the error output of a Spring Boot Controller?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

I have implemented a simple controller with a simple request / response.

> Controller

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloWorldController extends AbstractRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HelloWorldResponse sayHello(@Valid @RequestBody HelloWorldRequest request) {

        String message = String.format("Hello %s!", request.getSayHelloTo());
        return new HelloWorldResponse(message);
    }

}
```

> Request

```
public class HelloWorldRequest {

    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String sayHelloTo;

    protected HelloWorldRequest() {

    }

    public HelloWorldRequest(String sayHelloTo) {
        this.sayHelloTo = sayHelloTo;
    }

    public String getSayHelloTo() {
        return sayHelloTo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HelloWorldRequest{" +
                "sayHelloTo='" + sayHelloTo + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

When i want to test the correct output for the default error handling i seem to be unable to check the output of the default json format using a unit test. The response always seems to be empty. When i fire the request via a normal curl command is see a correct response. I assume this is because the returned JSON cannot be mapped on the HelloWorldResponse. Is there any way of checking if the returned output is valid on the response body?

> Test

```
class TestSpec extends Specification {

    MockMvc mockMvc

    def setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new HelloWorldController()).build()
    }

    def "Test simple action"() {
        when:
        def response = mockMvc.perform(post("/hello")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content('{"sayHelloTo": ""}')
        )

        then:
        response.andExpect(status().isOk())
    }
}
```

> Json Response

```
 {
       "timestamp" : 1426615606,
       "exception" : "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
       "status" : 400,
       "error" : "Bad Request",
       "path" : "/welcome",
       "message" : "Required String parameter 'name' is not present"
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your test?

Comment: Damn.. forgot the test indeed! Added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

try to debug with print() method, may be exception is thrown during execution.

`MvcResult andReturn = mockMvc.perform(get("/api")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andReturn();`

Answer (score 0):

The `@Controller` class you posted and the Test case (and response) don't seem to match (you're calling `/hello` in your test case and your `@RequestMapping` says `/welcome` ... Can we see the correct code? It looks like you have a `@RequestParam("name")` set, but you're not passing it.